# create PDF using tcpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to create pdf. PDF creation is working but i want to format those data. but i am not getting desired output.
i want following format for my PDF(Attached image), but i am not getting. Please help to get output in desired format.

my code is this:

```
<?php  

// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');


// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetTitle('Lorem Ipsum');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->AddPage();
$appendBlock = '';
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {     
  $appendBlock .= '<table><tr>
  <td>
  <img class="hw" style="width:150px;" src="'.$bar_code.'"> '.$username.'
  <b style="float:right;">Date:</b> <br/>
  '9-4-2015'
  'address of the user'
  '887766554433,009988775566'
  <b>Description:</b>'.Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum.'
  <b>ProductCode:</b>'2012' 'red' '9'
  '10-4-2015'
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>';
}

//mprd($appendBlock);
// create some HTML content
$html = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
'.$style.'
</head>
<body>
<section id="page">
'.$appendBlock.'
</section>
</body>
</html>';
// output the HTML content
//$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);

// set default font subsetting mode
//$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// set font
// $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11);


// $pdf->writeHTML($html, '', 0, '', false, 0, false, false, 0);
$pdf->writeHTML($html);

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// ---------------------------------------------------------
$name = strtotime('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

[image]

I am getting this type of format:
[image]

Comment: @craig but i have already integrated tcpdf.. is it not possible in tcpdf?

Comment: What exactly you need in terms of format? @rick

Comment: I don't have idea about tcpdf but check this link if this will help you to solve quickly -https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf

Comment: @Testing i have posted image, i want that type of format

Comment: And currently what you are getting if its your expected output? @rick

Comment: it is not in that format

Comment: should i show image for that pdf?

Comment: Yes, you should have posted it please. @rick

Comment: Post complete data of `$appendBlock` @rick

Comment: what do you want to ask?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74857/discussion-between-rick-and-testing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should consider changing your PDF Library to mPDF which you can download using this link below.

Link to Library Version 5.7: http://mpdf1.com/repos/MPDF57.zip

Unzip and upload the folder to your site root directory and adjust your path as per your required directory structure.

Based on the code you have provided, consider here is your complete html code that we are going to consider as final output in order to have this for pdf file.

Make all the suitable adjustments as per your requirements as it should best work for your in all cases.

As you are doing the PDF files for THAI Language so you need to define the Language parameter in your initialization.

`$mpdf  =   new mPDF('th');`

and for setting default font you can do: `$mpdf->SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_THAIVIET);`

For further reference you can read this manual for adding THAI fonts:

http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=453

Here is your final code:

```
<?php  
 $appendBlock = '<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="hw" style="width:150px;" src="AMC_AA23"> MOHSIN <b style="float:right;">Date:</b> <br/>
      9-4-2015
      เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์, เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์,เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์
      887766554433,009988775566 <b>Description:</b>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum <b>ProductCode:</b>2012 red 9
      10-4-2015 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="hw" style="width:150px;" src="AMC_AA23"> MOHSIN <b style="float:right;">Date:</b> <br/>
      9-4-2015
      เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์, เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์,เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์
      887766554433,009988775566 <b>Description:</b>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum <b>ProductCode:</b>2012 red 9
      10-4-2015 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="hw" style="width:150px;" src="AMC_AA23"> MOHSIN <b style="float:right;">Date:</b> <br/>
      9-4-2015
      เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์, เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์,เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์
      887766554433,009988775566 <b>Description:</b>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum <b>ProductCode:</b>2012 red 9
      10-4-2015 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="hw" style="width:150px;" src="AMC_AA23"> MOHSIN <b style="float:right;">Date:</b> <br/>
      9-4-2015
      เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์, เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์,เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์</p>
      887766554433,009988775566 <b>Description:</b>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum <b>ProductCode:</b>2012 red 9
      10-4-2015 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="hw" style="width:150px;" src="AMC_AA23"> MOHSIN <b style="float:right;">Date:</b> <br/>
      9-4-2015
      เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์, เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์,เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์
      887766554433,009988775566 <b>Description:</b>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum <b>ProductCode:</b>2012 red 9
      10-4-2015 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="hw" style="width:150px;" src="AMC_AA23"> MOHSIN <b style="float:right;">Date:</b> <br/>
      9-4-2015
      เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์, เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์,เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์
      887766554433,009988775566 <b>Description:</b>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum <b>ProductCode:</b>2012 red 9
      10-4-2015 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="hw" style="width:150px;" src="AMC_AA23"> MOHSIN <b style="float:right;">Date:</b> <br/>
      9-4-2015
      เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์, เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์,เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์
      887766554433,009988775566 <b>Description:</b>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum <b>ProductCode:</b>2012 red 9
      10-4-2015 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="hw" style="width:150px;" src="AMC_AA23"> MOHSIN <b style="float:right;">Date:</b> <br/>
      9-4-2015
      เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์, เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์,เรดมอนด์พาร์ทเม้นท์,
      887766554433,009988775566 <b>Description:</b>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum <b>ProductCode:</b>2012 red 9
      10-4-2015 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
';


require_once('mpdf.php');
$mpdf   =   new mPDF('th');
$mpdf->SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_THAIVIET);
$html   =   '<p lang="th">'.$appendBlock.'</p>';
$html   =   iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$html);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__)."/myfile.pdf", "F");
?>
```